# Laravel (5.7) Eloquent Many to Many with query on both sides

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

Say I have a users, roles, and a pivot table. I have belongsToMany set up for both Role and User.

**User Model**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

...
use App\Models\Role;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
  ...
  public function roles()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, "UserRoles", "userId", "roleId")
                ->withPivot("read", "write", "update", "delete")
                ->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

**Role Model**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

...
use App\User;

class Role extends Model
{
  ...
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "UserRoles", "roleId", "userId")
                ->withPivot("read", "write", "update", "delete")         
                ->withTimestamps();
  }

}
```

**Table "Users"**:

```
userId username
1      admin
2      johndoe
3      menghour
```

**Table "Roles"**:

```
roleId roleName
1      Admin
2      HR
3      Account
```

**Pivot Table "UserRoles"**:

```
id     userId   roleId   read   write   update   delete
1      1        1        1      1       1        1
2      1        2        1      1       1        1
3      1        3        1      1       1        1
4      2        2        1      0       0        0
5      3        3        1      1       1        0
```

My question is how I can get filter in pivot table.

**For example**: I want to filter only `userId` or `roleId` or both `userId and roleId`

if I select `user = admin` in blade template, I want to get all roles that user have.
expected result:

```
username    roleName

admin       Admin
admin       HR
admin       Account
```

if I select option `role = HR` in blade template,, I want to get all user that role have.
expected result:

```
username    roleName

admin       HR
johndoe     HR
```

if I select option `user = admin` and `role = HR`, I want to get only specific user and role.
expected result:

```
username    roleName

admin       HR
```

I've tired:

```
User::whereHas("roles", function ($query) use ($request) {
      if ($request->userId) {
        $query->where("userRoles.userId", "=", $request->userId);
      }
      if ($request->roleId) {
        $query->where("userRoles.roleId", "=", $request->roleId);
      }
    })->get();
```

note: I'm using Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query to filter data as per your example.

The function `whereHas` is used to retrieve all the users with a given role. To get the roles of user you have to use `with` function.

```
$user = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($request) {
            if ($request->roleId) {
                $query->where("userRoles.roleId", "=", $request->roleId);
            }
        })
        // It will give you the user's role data.
        ->with('roles');

// It will check in users table if you have applied the filter by user.
if ($request->userId) {
    $user = $user->where("users.id", "=", $request->userId);
}

$user = $user->get();
```

You could also try this query to filter data as per your example. This query will give you the user with particular that role which has you given in roles object.
For Example: if you select option role = HR in blade template.

```
$user = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($request) {
        if ($request->roleId) {
            $query->where("userRoles.roleId", "=", $request->roleId);
        }
    })
    // It will give you the user data with a particular given role which you has passed in the request.
    ->with(['roles' => function($query) use($request) {
        if ($request->roleId) {
            $query->where("roles.id", "=", $request->roleId);
        }
    }]);

// It will check in users table if you have applied the filter by user.
if ($request->userId) {
    $user = $user->where("users.id", "=", $request->userId);
}

$user = $user->get();
```

Comment: You saved my life. THANKS very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `wherePivot()` or `wherePivotIn()` methods:

```
User::roles()->wherePivot('roleId',$request->roleId)
    ->wherePivot('userId',$request->userId)
    ->get()
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many